# Debug a dynamically loaded C++/CLI DLL from a C++ application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, dynamic-loading

I'm new to C++ in Visual Studio.

I developed a VS solution with:

- a C++/CLI DLL project (A)
- a C++ console project (B), which dynamically loads A using `LoadLibraryW`

When I run B I need to debug also inside A. But breakpoints in A's code are not working, they have a warning glyph saying it is not possible to break here.

I have tried many settings but nothing worked. Isn't it an easy task? Thanks!

Comment: Project > Properties > Debugging > Debugger Type = Mixed.   And Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick the one that resembles "managed compatibility mode".  LoadLibrary doesn't magically enable managed code, the CLR needs to be loaded and initialized first.  Use COM or custom CLR hosting.  Or if you really, really, really have to then use a __declspec(dllexport) entrypoint.  You don't have to, exceptions are very hard to deal with.

Comment: @HansPassant it's not the first time you save me!! :) Thank you very much. Setting Debugger Type to Mixed solved it. "Use managed compatibility mode" was already checked. Could you please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? Anyway I use __declspec(dllexport) because otherwise I could not GetProcAddress of my DLL methods... and I don't know other ways...

Comment: @HansPassant OK, I'll publish it... anyway I can't understand the downvote that someone gave me

Comment: I set Debuggermode to Mixed on both projects, and set Managed Compat. what do you mean by "the clr needs to be loaded first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @HansPassant, the solution is to set this properties:

- Project > Properties > Debugging > Debugger Type = Mixed
- Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick "Use managed compatibility mode".

`LoadLibrary` doesn't magically enable managed code, the CLR needs to be loaded and initialized first.